# Is the SSL Certificate in a web-browser for a web app the same as the SAML 2.0 security cert?

Tags: ssl, certificate, single-sign-on, x509certificate, saml

This might not be a very intelligent question, but I have done my homework of looking around for the answer and I cannot seem to find it.  I am still to new to use SAML terms in this post, so I will define below how I am using them.

Authentication = My company has implemented SAML so that our AD/LDAP authenticates all our users to other applications that we use

Service Provider = is the company providing the application that is relying in our LDAP authentication using SAML 2.0

As I understand the problem we are having is.  There is a certificate used inside the implementation of our SAML 2.0, this certificate will expire soon, and the moment it does all Service Providers will be unable to authenticate.

I am trying to find out were/how to change this certificate, but I am getting confuse with the SSL certificate that the web browser uses for HTTP.

Any suggestions will be great.

I just added a related question in the following link: [Expiring Certificate will stop working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820456/will-my-saml-2-0-sso-implementation-continue-working-after-the-x509-certificate-e)

---

Adding some information.  The X509 Certificate was self-signed by our company. My contact told me that they will re-issue the same certificate.  Will I have to send a public key to the SPs?  Or I just change mine, and is transparent for them?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "SSL certificate" is flawed. X.509 certificates existed before SSL appeared, and they are not related to SSL. They are *used* in SSL, but this is just one of the uses.

You need to find out what the original certificate is and what certificate authority issued it (or it is a self-signed certificate). Then you can move further in getting or creating a new certificate (or reissuing the current one).

Update: if the certificate is self-signed, then the other parties probably added it to trusted certs list explicitly in order to accept it. So the re-issued certificate should also be added explicitly (IOW you'd need to send the public part to other parties).

Comment: Hi Eugene, If I understand correctly.  One of my options may be to re-issue the current certificate which will mean no change in any end. is this right?

Comment: @Geo this is not exactly so. If the certificate expires, then "reissue" means issuing similar certificate but keep old public and private key. This is a newly issued certificate with different validity period anyway and you will need to replace the old cert with the new one. Also, if the other side explicitly trusted some particular certificate with certain parameters, you might need to change the other side too. But this is usually not needed. It's hard to say without inspecting the complete environment.

Answer (score 1):

@Geo - is your cert for your SAML implementation self-signed (aka self-issued) or signed by a 3rd Party Cert Authority? Also, what product are you using as your SAML Identity Provider? Do you know how the original was generated?

Comment: My SAML cert is not self-signed.  I am trying to find out who is the CA.  I don't know what I am using for my Id Provider, I think it is a Microsoft product, but not sure.  I hope this helps.

Comment: If you are using ADFS, you should be able to view the Certificate used for signing via the ADFS Management Console. The certificate will tell you who issued it once you look at the details. However, even if you renew your cert, your SPs will need a new public key from you (showing the new expiration) in order to continue validation Assertions you generate.

Comment: Thanks Ian.  I just added some more information at the end of my post.